# why Python Generator is only inserting the first value?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have created a generator to read images from a folder and calculate aggregated Laplacian coefficient for each channel. Then I try to call the generator through a loop to append the red Laplacian coefficient for all 50 images to a list called data. But instead of 50 data length is 1. Only the first value is getting inserted. I want to know the reason behind this and how to resolve this?

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters

# creat list of file name
filename = []
for f in glob.glob('./dataset 2/train/category_id 0/*.jpg'):
    filename.append(f)

def Load_Image(file):
    for f in file:
        image = Image.open(f)
        lap = scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace(image)
        lap_mat0 = np.matrix(lap[:,:,0])
        lap_mat0 = lap_mat0.sum()      
    yield lap_mat0

data = []

for r in Load_Image(filename):
    data.append([r])

len(data) # getting 1 here
```

Comment: Add one tab before `yield lap_mat0`

Comment: Indent the `yield ...` statement so that it runs once per iteration of your `for` loop.